# Crystal Report Date Range Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

i'm using Crystal Reports and I have an output like this (group by day):

(This output calculation is from 00:00 to 23:59 each day..)

```
  Date (dd/mm/yyyy)     Weight
   -----------------------------------------
    01-01-2013            4000
    02-01-2013            3000
    03-01-2013            6000
    04-01-2013            5000
```

How can I make it by time range like 01-01-2013 6:00AM to 04-01-2013 6:00AM and the output still as per day:
(I pretend the half of current day + half of the next day)

```
  Date (dd/mm/yyyy)     Weight
   -----------------------------------------
    01-01-2013            3500 ( =half of 01-01-2013 and 02-01-2013)
    02-01-2013            4500 ( =half of 02-01-2013 and 03-01-2013)
    03-01-2013            5500 ( =half of 03-01-2013 and 04-01-2013)
    04-01-2013            2500 ( =half of 04-01-2013 and so on..)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does the source data include a time (other than everything at 12:00:00)?

Comment: yes, example: all the data from 11-feb-2013 6:30AM up to 12-feb-2013 6:30AM is equal to 1 day of 11-feb-2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to check the time whether it's before or after 12:00 noon.  If it's 11:59:59 or less, add it to the previous day.  Anything after, current day.  Create a formula using something like this

```
    IF TIME({yourdatetime}) <= TIME(11,59,59) THEN
       DATE({yourdatetime}) - 1
    ELSE 
       DATE({yourdatetime})
```

Then group by the formula and format the group header for just the date.